# Google Assistant service for Raspberry Pi zero - Illegal Instruction

Tags: google-assistant-sdk

Installation on Pi zero.
The installation was successful, but when I tried sample code

```
googlesamples-assistant-hotword --project_id my-dev-project --device_model_id my-model
```

It returns `Illegal Instruction`.

The pushtotalk sample didn't work neither.

Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the assistant to work on Pi 0 with pushtotalk sample by installing `python -m pip install --upgrade --no-binary :all: grpcio` before the SDK installation.

However, the assistant will either take forever to give me NO response or not able to finish the response, in either situation, I'll have to close the terminal to end the session. I've opened an issue in github, and it seems like an incompatibility error in the gRPC package.   https://github.com/googlesamples/assistant-sdk-python/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

The hotword sample uses the Google Assistant Library, which is not available on the Raspberry Pi Zero.

Comment: Which sample is available for the pi zero? the doc seemed to migrated the two together with no specification.

Comment: The `pushtotalk` sample may work, although there have been some issues with the gRPC target for arm6. You may want to instead go with the full [AIY kit system image](https://aiyprojects.withgoogle.com/voice/)

Answer (score 0):

try run again

python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-library

python -m pip install --upgrade google-assistant-sdk[samples]

Answer (score 0):

Been having the same problem with raspberry pi 1. Only solution I could find so far is to use the pushtotalk and have echo automatically input newline using this.

```
googlesamples-assistant-pushtotalk --project-id gassist-d4d83 --device-model-id gassist-d4d83-rpi-meicej|echo -n
```

That does the job for me. Don't know if it helps anyone.

Edit: Only part that's bad is, it's always listening. Maybe I can modify the code.